# Need a time delay before my Typing code starts and time delay before the second iteration

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Can anyone help me out in applying time delay before my type writing starts and also before second loop. As its a multi line typing having bullet points, can we apply time delay between every bullet point separately as well? Below is the code. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>



<pre id="typing" </pre>

   

<script>
var typeString = ['• I m Mr. Frits.\n• and I love Pakistan...:)'];

var i = 0;
var count = 0
var selectedText = '';
var text = '';
(function type() {
  if (count == typeString.length) {
    count = 0;
  }
  selectedText = typeString[count];
  text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
  document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = text.fontsize(6);
  document.getElementById('typing').style.fontFamily = "monospace";
  document.getElementById("typing").style.color = "black";
  document.getElementById("typing").style.fontWeight = "normal";

  if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
    count++;
    i = 0;

  }
  setTimeout(type, 300);
}());

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
      break;
    }
  }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added couple lines of code in your JavaScript. Try replacing yours.

It is basically assigning longer delay when it meets a new line `\n`.

```
var typeString = ['• I m Mr. Frits.\n• and I love Pakistan...:)'];

var i = 0;
var count = 0;
var selectedText = '';
var text = '';
function type() {
  if (count == typeString.length) {
    count = 0;
    /* Wait for some time after all lines done */
    sleep(2000);
  }
  selectedText = typeString[count];
  text = selectedText.slice(0, ++i);
  document.getElementById('typing').innerHTML = text.fontsize(6);
  document.getElementById('typing').style.fontFamily = "monospace";
  document.getElementById("typing").style.color = "black";
  document.getElementById("typing").style.fontWeight = "normal";

  if (text.length === selectedText.length) {
    count++;
    i = 0;
  }
  
  /* SOLUTION : wait two seconds when new line */
  if (typeString[0][i-1] == '\n')  {
    setTimeout(type, 2000);
  } else {
    setTimeout(type, 300);
  }
  
};

/* Start typing after some time */
setTimeout(type, 2000);

function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's great. I need one more thing, on page loading, start typing after some time delay of our choice, and when all lines end, text should stay for some seconds before next iteration.

Comment: Edited my answer for the addition. Also, your html needs correction. `<pre id="typing"> </pre>`